# how to get multiple js.erb executions (rails + ajax + jquery)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm working at a little online status manager for some subdomains I've got inside my project.

The problem is that checking the online state of each subdomain is a bit slow, so I've decided to first render just a table with the name of the subdomain and then to check the online status by AJAX, showing an online / offline image.

I've implemented a working AJAX status checker, but the problem is that until ALL subdomains are checked, the result won't render on the site so it's not a huge improvement because user must wait a long while without actually knowing if everything's working fine.

My goal is that user can observe the subdomain status check getting updated one-per-one, without having to wait until all the checkings are done.

My idea is to use something like this:

```
/app/controllers/status_controller.rb
@institutes = Institute.all

  respond_to do |format|

    @institutes.each do |inst|
      format.js { render :locals => { :institute => inst } }
    end
```

And

```
/app/view/status/status.js.erb
<% # Iterates through institutes and checks their online availability %>
$('.instance_name[value="<%= institute.cms_instance_name %>"]')
  .next('.cm_online')
  .html("<%= institute.cm_online? %>");
```

Now, it does only update the first element in the array and stops rendering more iterations. Is there another way to get this done?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but did you try this?

```
/app/controllers/status_controller.rb
@institutes = Institute.all
  respond_to do |format|
       format.js { render :locals => { :institutes => @institutes} }
  end
```

And

```
/app/view/status/status.js.erb
<% institutes.each do |institute| %>
       $('.instance_name[value="<%= institute.cms_instance_name %>"]')
  .next('.cm_online')
  .html("<%= institute.cm_online? %>");
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes I did and there was the same issue: unless all the checking is done, no changes are shown in browser.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've worked this one out. The problem was my approach, because once the page gets rendered, it won't render again so that's why the loop in the controller wasn't working.

So I just created a loop inside the application.js, so each time the user hits the update link, it will launch an AJAX call for each element in the subdomain list:

```
function institute_call_ajax() {
    $('.instance_name').each(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/status/status",
            data: 'instance_name=' + $(this).val()
        });
    });
}
```

Then I capture the identification name of the institute (subdomain) and send it to the .js.erb file so it updates the view.

```
def status
    @institutes = Institute.find_all_by_live(true)
    institute = Institute.find_by_cms_instance_name(params[:instance_name])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :locals => { :institute => institute } }

      format.html # status.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @institutes }
    end
end
```

Voilà!